# How can you tell if a normal subgroup induces a semidirect product?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Suppose I have some (finite) group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$.  I know there's no full characterization of whether $G \cong N \rtimes G/N$, but are there well-known tests I can use to answer the question in common cases?  Moreover, if $G$ is a semidirect product, then as we know $G \ge H \cong G/N$...but how do I explicitly find the elements of $H$?  They lie in the cosets of $N$, but I don't know any good way to figure out, short of exhaustive testing, which the "right" elements are. Any suggestions for how to approach this appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes you can find the complement as the point stabilizer for a suitable group action. Look for example at the proofs of the theorems of Schur-Zassenhaus and of Gaschuetz in the book "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher. Another example is the Frattini argument: If a group $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$ such that a normal subgroup $N$ acts transitively, then $G = G_\omega N$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. If $N_\omega=1$, then $G_\omega$ is a complement of $N$ in $G$.

Comment: An example using the Frattini argument you can find in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335969/669) by Derek Holt.

Answer (score 4):

A group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ determines a [short exact sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence)

$$1 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 1$$

and this short exact sequence exhibits $G$ as a semidirect product if and only if the map $G \to G/N$ [splits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), or equivalently if it has a right inverse. Given such a right inverse, the elements of $H$ are given by the image of the right inverse.

A simple example where this doesn't occur is the short exact sequence

$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1.$$

A sufficient condition for splitting is given by the [Schur-Zassenhaus theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem): such a splitting always exists if $\gcd(|N|, |G/N|) = 1$. A simpler special case of this, using the Sylow theorems, is that such a splitting always exists if the order of $G/N$ is the order of a Sylow subgroup of $G$.