# How to compute the automorphism group of split metacyclic groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to calculate the automorphism group of an affine subgroup $$G=\mathbb{Z}_p\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{k}\leq\text{AGL}(1,p).$$

One might guess $\text{Aut}(G)=\text{AGL}(1,p)$. And this matches what I got in GAP after checking a couple examples. However, it seems proving it through by definition is messy and not particular easy. So I have been pondering a while what will be a better way to approach? Any suggestions?

Comment: How big is $k$? Can't be too small...

Comment: @anon: $k$ can be any integer that divides $p-1$. But I believe it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: @j.p.:$\text{Aut}(\mathbb Z_p)=\mathbb Z_{p-1}$. So the kernel shouldn't be trivial. However, if we can show the kernel is $\mathbb Z_p$ then we are done.

Comment: I think you can show that the kernel of the homomorphism $Aut(G) \to Aut(Z_p)$ (that exists since $Z_p$ is characteristic in $G$) is $Z_p$: If $\phi\in Aut(G)$ centralizes $Z_p$, i.e., $\phi(x)=x$ for a generator of $Z_p$, then take a generator $y$ of $Z_k$, which acts by multiplication on $Z_p$, let's say $x^y = x^a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{N}$. Now $x^a = \phi(x^a) = \phi(x^y) = \phi(x)^{\phi(y)} = x^{\phi(y)}$, so $\phi(y) = x^b\cdot y$ for some $b\in \mathbb{N}$. But all elements of the form $x^b\cdot y\in G$ are conjugated by an element of $Z_p$. (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation of last comment) So $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y$, and $\phi$ centralizes $x$ and maps $y$ to a conjugate $y^z$ for some $z\in Z_p$ (as $Z_k$ is abelian). Hence $\phi$ is conjugation by $z$, an element of $Z_p$, proving the claim. To get $AGL(1, p)\le Aut(G)$ you probably know already that it follows from $G$ being normal in it with trivial centralizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick outline argument. You need to assume that $k>1$ or the result isn't true. Then $Z(G)=1$, so we can embed $G$ in $A:={\rm Aut}(G)$ and, since $G \unlhd {\rm AGL}(1,p)$, we have $G < {\rm AGL}(1,p) \le A$.

Write $G = P \rtimes Q$ with $P=C_p$, $Q=C_k$. Then $P \lhd A$ and the complements of $P$ in $G$ are conjugate so, by the Frattini Argument $A=GR$ with $R=N_A(Q)$ and, since $R \cap P=1$, $A = P \rtimes R$.

Now,  $[C_R(P),Q] \le C_G(P) \cap Q = 1$, so $C_R(P) \le C_A(G) = 1$. Hence $|R| \le |{\rm Aut}(P)|=p-1$, so $G={\rm AGL}(1,p)$.

That was trickier that I expected - more detail on request!

Comment: It is a brilliant idea to apply the Frattini Argument to $Q$. But I am just not sure how you get $\text{C}_A(G)=1$. I think you are using the fact that $G$ is embedded in $A$, and so any element cannot centralize $G$ or it will induce a trivial automorphism. But saying $G$ as the inner automorphism group, then the elements in $\text{C}_A(G)$ is just the elements that commutes with the inner automorphisms. In this sense can we still say $\text{C}_A(G)=1$? I am not sure.